# unable to attached a custom CSS on a site page using "code snippet"

Tags: 2013, development, css, page-layout, snippet

I have added a new aspx site page inside my team site and I want to reference a custom style sheet inside this site page only. So what I did is I edited the page then I chose to add a code snippet, and i add the following inside the code snippet :-

```
 <link href="/Style%20Library/Custom%20CSS/s.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Once I add the above reference inside the vcode snippet, I can see that the layout was affected directly, but when I click on apply button, it seems something hangs as I keep seeing the following page for more than 10 minutes till now :

[image]

i also try to add the css rules directly inside a `<style>` tag on the code snippet instead of referencing the css file. and i also can see the effect once i copied the css rules, but when i save the page the css effect will disappear , and i will get the following inside the code snippet:-

```
<style unselectable="on"></style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to embed javascript this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It worked for me